Why does the variable never pass between JetPack Compose screens?
I am trying to pass 1 or more variables between 2 screens:
MainActivity (where the navigation is located)
OptionsScreen (where the desired values ​​to pass are located)
ScanStudenQrScreen (where I want to receive the parameters)
In the following code:
In my OptionsScreen file I have code and some parts are:
In OptionsScreen:
fun OptionsScreen(
optionsViewmodel: OptionsViewmodel = getViewModel(),
position: Int,
navigateToActivitiesScreen: (Int) -> Unit,
navigateTocardScreen: (Int) -> Unit,
navigateToActivitySelection: () -> Unit,
navigateToSelectionScreen: () -> Unit,
navigateToLoginScreen: () -> Unit,
navigateToUpdateMyDataScreen: () -> Unit,
navigateToContactsScreen:() -> Unit,
navigateToNewsScreen:() -> Unit,
navigateToScanStudentQr: (String) -> Unit

)
if (showDialogFlagStudenAttendence) {
        CommonDialogTwoButtons(
            title = stringResource(id = R.string.title_student_attendence_exit),
            body = "",
            firstOptionText = stringResource(id = R.string.option1_student_attendence_exit),
            secondOptionText = stringResource(id = R.string.option2_student_attendence_exit),
            firstOption = {
                mainActivity.startUserInactivityTimer()
                navigateToScanStudentQr("INGRESO")
                showDialogFlagStudenAttendence = false
            },
            secondOption = {
                mainActivity.startUserInactivityTimer()
                navigateToScanStudentQr("SALIDA")
                showDialogFlagStudenAttendence = false
            }
        )
    }

In MainActivity:
navigateToScanStudentQr = { attendanceType ->
                                        currentScreen = MyConstantes.scanStudentQrScreennavController.navigate(NavScreen.ScanStudentQr.routeWithArgument)
                                    }


composable(
                    route = NavScreen.ScanStudentQr.routeWithArgument,
                    arguments = listOf(navArgument(NavScreen.ScanStudentQr.argument0) { type = NavType.StringType }),
                    enterTransition = { enterTransition(this) },
                    exitTransition = { exitTransition(this) },
                    popEnterTransition = { popEnterTransition(this) },
                    popExitTransition = { popExitTransition(this) }
                ) { backStackEntry ->
                    /*val attendanceType = "XXXX"*/
                    /*val attendanceType = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(NavScreen.ScanStudentQr.argument0) ?: "TEST"*/

                    val attendanceType =
                        backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(NavScreen.ScanStudentQr.argument0)
                            ?: return@composable

                    KoinContext {
                        ScanStudentQrScreen(
                            attendanceType = attendanceType,
                            pressBackButton = {
                                navController.popBackStack()
                            },
                            navigateToSaveStudentAttendance = { index, value ->
                                currentScreen = MyConstantes.saveStudentAttendanceScreen
                                /*navController.navigate("${NavScreen.SaveStudentAttendance.route}/$index/$value")*/
                                navController.navigate(NavScreen.SaveStudentAttendance.route)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }

In ScanStudentQrScreen
@Composable
fun ScanStudentQrScreen(
    attendanceType: String,
    pressBackButton: () -> Unit,
    navigateToSaveStudentAttendance: (Int, String) -> Unit
) {
    Napier.i("ScanStudentQrScreen")
    Napier.i("ScanStudentQrScreen - attendanceType $attendanceType")

But whenever I place a log it shows me the literal text "attendanceType" and not the value selected in the section of the INGRESO or SALIA buttons
If more code is needed I can put it but your help please

In MainActivity, when you navigate to ScanStudentQrScreen, you need to ensure that the argument is correctly passed along with the navigation route.
navigateToScanStudentQr = { attendanceType ->
    currentScreen = MyConstantes.scanStudentQrScreennavController.navigate(
        "${NavScreen.ScanStudentQr.route}/$attendanceType"
    )
}

When retrieving the argument in ScanStudentQrScreen, ensure that you're correctly accessing the argument from the backStackEntry:
val attendanceType =
    backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(NavScreen.ScanStudentQr.argument0)
        ?: return@composable

